# If `[` is a function for subsetting in R, what is `]`?

Tags: r, syntax, primitive

I'm reading the advanced R introduction by Hadley Wickham, where he states that [ (and +, -, {, etc) are functions, so that [ can be used in this manner

```
> x <- list(1:3, 4:9, 10:12)
> sapply(x, "[", 2)
[1]  2  5 11
```

Which is perfectly fine and understandable. But if [ is the function required to subset, does ] have another use rather than a syntactical one?

I found that:

```
> `]`
Error: object ']' not found
```

so I assume there is no other use for it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the fundamental difference between syntax and semantics. Semantics require that — in R — things like subsetting and `if` etc are *functions*. That’s why R defines functions `` `[` ``, `` `if` `` etc.

And then there’s *syntax*. And R’s syntax dictates that the syntax for `if` is either `if (condition) expression` or `if (condition) expression else expression`. Likewise, the syntax for subsetting in R is `obj[args…]`. That is, `]` is simply a syntactic element and it has no semantic equivalent, no corresponding function (same as `else`).

To make this perhaps even clearer:

- `[` and `]` are syntactic elements in R that delimit a subsetting expression.
- By contrast, `` `[` `` (note the backticks!) is a *function* that implements the subsetting operation.

Comment: Another way to think of it is that `]` is used by R's parser to identify where the call to `[` ends.

Comment: That is what I assumed but  wanted to check up on, since a couple of lines lines above this example the following quote was placed:“To understand computations in R, two slogans are helpful:

Everything that exists is an object.
Everything that happens is a function call."
— John Chambers

Comment: Ah, So this means that ] by and of itself is not a syntatical element, only when in the combination [...], where it refers to the primitive function` `[` `(in backticks)?

Comment: @Xizam Yes, exactly. And the Chambers quote is still accurate: `]` isn’t something “that happens”, nor is it something that “exists” (at least not in R’s semantics). It’s simply syntactic sugar. In the same vein, comments are neither objects nor functions: they only exist in R’s code representation, not in its semantics.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Excellent, understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow though, I was expecting `]` to be a syntactical element, by default: indexing from the end. So I define it myself in my code:

```
 "]" <- function(x,y) if (y <= length(x)) x[length(x)+1-y] else NA
```

With the given example, then:

```
sapply(x, "]", 1)
[1]  3  9 12
sapply(x, "]", 2)
[1]  2  8 11
```

Comment: Looks a bit like (but not identical to) `tail`. Not sure I like the use of symbols instead of expressive names for functions.